# PayPal Change Default Currency

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am working on a donations website and I have set up a PayPal Sandbox Business Account.  Everything's fine, however I want to accept money in Euros and not $ as it is set by default.  How can this be done please?  Thanks :)

---Edit---

I did not use any APIs.  I just created a business account and used this code:

```
string temp_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=sponsorchild10@gmail.com&item_name=Sponsor a Child Society&amount=";
string PayPal = temp_url + Convert.ToString(donation);
Response.Redirect(PayPal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you use `currency_code` property.

*"This parameter represents a currency code. Possible values are "USD","EUR","GBP","YEN","CAD" etc. It is "USD" by default."*

Find more : [Use of the PayPal payment system in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Solved it :)  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you generate your request to paypal you can include a parameter stating which currency you want the transaction to be carried out in.